# How to add default value in multiple select box?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

I am using multiple select box to get collection of values. Now i want to set a default value for that. I tried the below but its not working. If you have any idea please share.

```
 <select name="protocols[]" multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-2" class="form-control" default="hls">
 <%videos.each do |option|%>
 <option><%=option%> </option>
 <%end%>
 </select>
```

Comment: Try giving `<option selected="selected">` to your code.

Comment: what is 'hls', is it from one of the options in videos?

Comment: yes @Surya . its one of the option

Comment: Try like this `<option selected="selected"> 'hls' </option>`

Comment: give reason also for downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
<select name="protocols[]" multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-2" class="form-control">
  <%videos.each do |option|%>
    <option value=<%= option %> <%= option == 'hls' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' %>><%=option%> </option>
  <%end%>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you post what's in `videos` object?

Comment: ["rtsp", "http_pd","rtmp","hls"]

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is already exits.
You need to find first solutions then ask if not found.

I hope you can find your answer in below link:  [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172279/display-previously-selected-choices-in-multiple-select-form-rails)

Where @arr_selected is saved selected values array

```
<% @arr_selected = ['first','second'] %>    
     <select name="protocols[]" multiple="multiple" id="form-field-select-2" class="form-control" default="hls">
     <%videos.each do |option|%>
     <option <% (@arr_selected.include?(option)) ? "selected" : "" %> ><%=option%> </option>
     <%end%>
     </select>
```

Comment: i am not using rails tag. i am using html for select tag

Comment: for my requirement rails tag is not suitable. so i am using html

Comment: What is "videos"? option values or saved selected values?

Comment: it contains all the values which are needs to be displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54277/discussion-between-harsh4u-and-pooja-agarwal).